# How to instantiate EmbeddedActiveMQResource object for spring integration test?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-test, activemq-artemis, cucumber-junit

I am using EmbeddedActiveMQResource in my spring boot. While running the integration tests I see lots of `javax.jms.JMSException: Failed to create session factory` and this is because I am not instantiating this object globally. I instantiate this only in those test classes wherever necessary.

```
@Rule
public static EmbeddedActiveMQResource mqServer = new EmbeddedActiveMQResource("broker.xml");

private static WireMockServer wireMock = new WireMockServer(1020);

    @BeforeAll
    public static void beforeAll() {
        wireMock.start();
        mqServer.start();
    }

    @BeforeEach
    public void startWireMock() {
        wireMock.resetAll();
    }

    @AfterAll
    public static void stopWiremock() {
        wireMock.stop();
        mqServer.stop();
    }
```

Those test classes where I am not instantiating this objects is throwing `javax.jms.JMSException: Failed to create session factory`. Is there anyway to avoid this by instantiating gloabally?

Comment: I don't understand the circumstances which lead to the error. Can you whip up a quick demonstration and throw it into GitHub?

Comment: Sorry I can add only code snippets as I dont own this code.

Comment: You don't need to add the exact code. You just need a simple bit of code to reproduce the kind of error you're hitting. In other words, a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Probably all your test are integration tests against your `ApplicationContext`. I guess they are just `@SpringBootTest`. So, it is not a surprise that JMS connection factory in your application context cannot connect because there is not that embedded Active MQ broker for them.

I wonder why do you need to manage that ActiveMQ broker manually and don't let the auto-configuration to handle it for you since you really don't do unit tests in isolation: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#messaging.jms.artemis

Comment: The test which requires Artemis is not passing without it being instantiated 
@Rule
public static EmbeddedActiveMQResource mqServer = new EmbeddedActiveMQResource("broker.xml");

Comment: Right. We got it just from your question description. Or you should ensure all your integration tests come with that rule or see if you can have an embedded broker auto-configured. Or look if really all your tests have to integration, with that `@SpringBootTest` annotation.